# Unknown command rename on Cisco Router

Tags: cisco

I try to rename a file on a Cisco 2911 router by issuing

```
rename flash:/asa842-k8.bin flash:/old.bin
```

but get the error message

```
Router#rename flash:asa842-k8.bin flash:old.bin
              ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
    
Router#
```

I also tried

```
rename flash:asa842-k8.bin flash:old.bin
```

but the same error occurs. Is there any other command?

**Edit** the flash looks like this

```
Router#dir flash:
Directory of flash0:/

    5  -rw-     5571584          <no date>  asa842-k8.bin
    3  -rw-    33591768          <no date>  c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.151-4.M4.bin
    2  -rw-       28282          <no date>  sigdef-category.xml
    1  -rw-      227537          <no date>  sigdef-default.xml

255744000 bytes total (216324829 bytes free)
```

**I am using Cisco packet tracer**

Comment: Are you sure the url is correct?  try *dir flash:*

Comment: Hi and thank you. I have added the output into the question.

Comment: did you try *flash0*?

Comment: Yes i did but the same result.

Comment: I am using Cisco Packet Tracer, maybe thats the reason? But downloading and delete does work so i dont know why rename should not work.

Comment: Oh ok if this is packet tracer, well everything is possible. It is a limited simulator and we can expect major differences with real devices. Actually what would surprise me is that you were able to alter the flash of devices in packet tracer.

Comment: You can add a tftp server and download files, so i think you can alter the "flash". It is emulated anyway. At least i can download and delete. Just rename does not work. I can specify a destination file name as well. Nevermind, i have to do an update on a customer device and just wanted a dry run :D I hope on a real device it works as expected.

Comment: "It is emulated anyway. " , no it is simulated. It only includes a subset of features, targeted at CCNA level courses, and it doesn't run real IOS software. For emulators that run real IOS have a look at GNS3 (free) or Cisco VIRL (payed).

Comment: Did you try to copy the file to the new name and then delete the original?

Comment: Yes, that worked. It seems just the rename command is not implemented for whatever reason. Nevermind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the edit explaining this is actually within Packet Tracer, this is to be expected.

Packet Tracer doesn't run real IOS software, it only simulates basic features of Cisco devices, mainly targeted at CCNA courses.